# Passing a variable in JavaScript to open.window

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have variable which is i think global ,,so all my child functions must be able to get that variable,But i am getting a reference error,Variable not declared
Here is below code.Please help if i am doing any wrong thing.Thanku

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
        <head>
         <script>
            var Test1Object = 'Testing'; // This is my variable
         </script>
        <script src = 'ch.js'>
        </script>
        </head>
      <body>
        <button onclick="openwindow()">Create window</button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

My Ch.js

```
(function(){

    alert(Test1Object)  // Here i am getting this object
   this.openwindow = function() {

    w =window.open("untitled.html",'TheNewpop','height=315,width=625');  
    w.document.write(
    "<body>"+

    "<\/body>" + 
    "<script src = \"windowpo.js\"><\/script>" // THis is where i reference my windowpo.js

    )
    w.document.close();
    w.focus();
}
 })()
```

My windowpo.js

```
(function(){
alert(Test1Object)  // Here  there is not Test1Object (Reference error)
})();
```

My issue is that in my windowp.js how can i get my Test1Object Variable...

Comment: it is not global to CH.js file. you need to declare the variable inside the file which will global only to that file

Comment: Did you include your **windowpo.js** in you **html** like you included your **ch.js** ?

Comment: It is global, but only to your original site and not the newly created popup. The popup gets a new execution context, so it has no access directly to the old one. You can share data using `postMessage()` though.

Comment: How to share the using postMessage? Can you explain that

Comment: @Lotus i have included it in Ch.js

Comment: The `w` object you get after calling `window.open()` is your reference to the popup window. Afaik it has a method called `postMessage()`, which can be used to send data to the other window. On th side of the popup you  add the respective eventlistener `window.addEventListener( 'message', ...)` to grab the data and process it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage for more details.

Comment: @Sirko What will be my target window instead of www.examp.com as i am running it locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy doing by just acessing your refrence inside the window by using `window.opener` like in this [runnable demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5xUH7L?p=preview). Inside your window application you can access it via `window.opener.Test1Object` where `window.opener` holds a reference of the JavaScript instance where it was opened. In that way you can access all the stuff you configured in your main application:

- Source: [window.opener MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)

#### View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Custom Plunker</title>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var Test1Object = 'Testing';
 </script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <a onclick="openwindow()">Open Window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

#### main.js

```
this.openwindow = function() {
  w = window.open(location.href+"untitled.html",'TheNewpop','height=315,width=625');  
  w.document.close(); 
  w.focus();
}
```

#### unitiled.html

```
Some Test
<script src="windowpo.js"></script>
```

#### windowpo.js

```
alert(window.opener.Test1Object);
```

Comment: `window.opener` is a reference to the original execution context anyways. So currently the line `w.Test1Object = Test1Object;` is redundant. But have to admit I did not know you could actually access the complete old context.

Answer (score 0):

As most other answers don't seem to even read the question properly, I'll add my 2 cents as an answer, too:

The main problem in your code, is that you have to JS execution contexts here: One for the original page (the HTML code you show) and one for the popup you open in `Ch.js`. In general both do not share any data, variables or whatever.

You have, however, a window object reference in your variable `w` after calling `window.open()`. You use this already to inject HTML code to the popup.

If you now want to have JS variables available in the popup JS context, you can either inject additional `<script>` tags into the popups HTML code and set the variables there (bad choice, imho) or use `postMessage()` to send data across. I give some sample code for the `postMessage()` variant below:

Ch.js

```
this.openwindow = function() {

  w = window.open("untitled.html",'TheNewpop','height=315,width=625');  
  w.document.write(
    "<body>"+
    "<\/body>" + 
    "<script src = \"windowpo.js\"><\/script>" // THis is where i reference my windowpo.js
    );
  w.document.close();
  w.focus();

  // wait for pupup to be ready
  window.addEventListener( 'message', function( e ){
    // send the variable
    if( e.data == 'inited' ) {
      w.postMessage( Test1Object, '*' );
    }
  })
}
```

windowpo.js

```
// wait for messages from opener
window.addEventListener( 'message', function( e ) {
  alert( e.data );
});

// tell the opener we are waiting
window.opener.postMessage( 'inited', '*' );
```

For some more information see the respective [MDN article on `Window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postmessage).

Comment: From the docs you should be able to insert `*` if only using the code just locally.

Comment: No still my alert is not firing

Comment: No need for events in this case.

Comment: Took me a while, but the reason for it not working is just a race-condition. At the point my above code sends the message, the JS file in the popup has not been loaded and hence can not receive the event. I'll adapt the code for documentation's sake, but for simple interactions lin's answer is probably much better suited,

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the variable before you include in any file. Simply create a script tag above the included files define it there.

```
<script type='text/javascript' > 
  var Test1Object = 'Testing';
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/Ch.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/windowpo.js'></script>
```

this way you should be able to use withing all files

Comment: I was not the down voter,,But  i have referenced it check my question

Comment: you adding the script tag dynamically right? then you can't use that variable. just try hard coding the above reference <script type='text/javascript' src='js/windowpo.js'></script>
it should work

Comment: No still not getting

Comment: document.write( '<script src = \"windowpo.js\"><\/script>'); this way you can't load the file according to my knowledge. look at the network tab to check whether the file is loaded or not

Comment: it is working for me by adding this <script src = 'windowpo.js'></script> to the main site

Comment: This solution does not consider the autors requirements. This will simply not work while the open window application is handled in as a seperate side. So i dont understand why you try to redeclare `var Test1Object = 'Testing';` inside the window application - this is not a parsing.

Comment: As I understand author is trying to access a variable withing the multiple files. problem is in windowpo.js file don't have access to the variable Test1Object. This is a solutions for that.

Comment: No its not, you dont understand the requirements and the limitations on this question. Check my answer and the plnkr to make yourself understood.